Job prospects in mathematical physics vs Statistics
I am at a crossroads in my academic journey and would greatly appreciate any job insights for these two career paths. I have a passion for both statistics and mathematical physics and am considering a career in one of these fields. While I am well aware that statistics is vastly more applicable to a wide range of jobs, I am much more interested in mathematical physics. However, I am uncertain about the career prospects for someone with a degree in mathematical physics, especially outside of academic research.
My Question:
What career opportunities are available for someone with a degree in mathematical physics outside of academia and research?

For context, if I were to study mathematical physics, the units would include subjects such as quantum mechanics, applied and ordinary differential equations, statistical mechanics, quantum chaos.

Background:

I enjoy problem-solving, working with data, and theoretical work, which makes both fields appealing to me.
I am open to various career paths and am not solely focused on staying within academia.
My interest leans more towards mathematical physics, and I want to explore all potential career opportunities in this field.

Any advice, personal experiences, or resources you can provide would be incredibly helpful as I make this important decision. Thank you!

Please only one question per post

No one can accurately predict the future, including the job market even two years out. Maybe do an experiment: Find five positions in statistics and five in mathematical physics. Explore what those would entail. At the same time, pursue summer internship to get (near) first-hand exposure. My two cents: It would be easier to switch from physics to statistics than the other way round.

You should be able to answer this question with Google. Go to your local job portal (Google for it if you don't know what it is) and put in "mathematical physics" or "statistics", then see what pops out.
I'm pretty sure you'll find far fewer results for mathematical physics, which is simply because that field is arcane enough that it's inscrutable to non-mathematical physicists. It does not mean you won't be able to get a job using your mathematical physics background, however. You can still search for phrases such as 'quantitative researcher', which has high overlap with the skills you learn in mathematical physics. Example job.
After you've looked at the jobs available, where you go next is up to you. If you're still doubtful, be sure to visit your university's career center.

Having my field be described as arcane makes me feel like I'm a warlock.
